# Fixed header under the navbar

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc.jquery.datatables

I am using jquery.dataTables fixed header and footer options, The problem is the header disappears behind the navbar I searched for a way to fix the headers so it is right under the navbar but I didn't find anything. I hope you guys can help. I don't want to remove the navbar.
thank you.

```
<head><link rel="stylesheet"type="text/css"href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.5/css/fixedHeader.dataTables.min.css" /></head> 

<style>
.body
{
    margin-top: -100px;
}
</style>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.2/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#example').DataTable({
            fixedHeader: {
                header: true,
                footer: true
            },
            "pageLength": 100
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out using dataTables reference.
https://datatables.net/reference/option/fixedHeader.headerOffset

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
       var table = $('#example').DataTable({
                fixedHeader: {
                    header: true,
                    footer: true,
                    headerOffset: 50
                },
                "pageLength": 100
            });

        });
```

Thank you. it seemed very hard to find, I just had to use the correct wording and search it.

Comment: Super. saved a lot of time.